# Tri-dimensional array as multiplication of vector and matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array `A` (shape = (a, 1)) and matrix `B` (shape = (b1, b2)). Want to multiply the latter by each element of the former to generate a tridimensional array (shape = (a, b1, b2)).

Is there a vectorized way to do this?

```
import numpy as np
A = np.random.rand(3, 1)
B = np.random.rand(5, 4)
C = np.array([ a * B for a in A ])
```

Comment: Look into `np.multiply.outer`.

Comment: Thanks. `np.multiply.outer(A, B)` worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways you can achieve this.
One is using [`np.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html), note that it will be necessary to introduce a second axis in `B` so both `ndarrays` can be multiplied:

```
C = np.dot(A,B[:,None])
print(C.shape)
# (3, 5, 4)
```

Using [`np.multiply.outer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html), as @divakar suggests:

```
C = np.multiply.outer(A,B)
print(C.shape)
# (3, 5, 4)
```

Or you could also use [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html):

```
C = np.einsum('ij,kl->ikl', A, B)
print(C.shape)
# (3, 5, 4)
```